# Mark in google maps a list of addresses - Android or PHP

Tags: android, list, google-maps, gmsplace

I have a list of addresses and I want to mark this places all in google maps(nearly 1k), getting maybe its cordinates to save them.
Actually I am not programming an app, but I know both lenguages (Android and PHP) and I think it is possible to do this with both. Any idea ? Thank in advance!

Comment: If you're not programming anything, then why are you asking your question?

Comment: Id like to see them marked on the map

Comment: Okay, then you should show something that you've tried. Yes, it's possible, however you can search elsewhere how to implement that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the google maps api?

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ReverseGeocoding

This is what you are looking for I think.

EDIT: to mark stars on map

```
    // In the following example, markers appear when the user clicks on the map.
// Each marker is labeled with a single alphabetical character.
var labels = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
var labelIndex = 0;

function initialize() {
  var bangalore = { lat: 12.97, lng: 77.59 };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 12,
    center: bangalore
  });

  // This event listener calls addMarker() when the map is clicked.
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    addMarker(event.latLng, map);
  });

  // Add a marker at the center of the map.
  addMarker(bangalore, map);
}

// Adds a marker to the map.
function addMarker(location, map) {
  // Add the marker at the clicked location, and add the next-available label
  // from the array of alphabetical characters.
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    label: labels[labelIndex++ % labels.length],
    map: map
  });

 }
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15417912)

Comment: I'll do it from now on but even though, he just asked for a way to do this, not a particular code. If he doesnt give any code I will not code it for him, I just referred to the official api where he can find how. Thanks for the advice though.

Comment: Thank Enrique, this was very useful for me. I understand now how to send with php several addresses and get its location. Do you have any idea where I can find the way to mark all of them into a google map (with stars or something like that?)

Comment: Oh, I think I find the answer thanks to google https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/mysql-to-maps